# Need MongoDB mapreduce function to split the data(field contains comma separated values)

Tags: mongodb

i need mapreduce to split the field contains comma separated values in mongodb and to count the values in the field.

Comment: Please consider including some useful information about the document you are trying to reduce so people could give relevant answers.

Answer (score 1):

I have created sample document shown below.

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5060017f6fd0f104e16540a2"), "field" : "1,2,3,4,5" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("506001866fd0f104e16540a3"), "field" : "1,2,3" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5060018e6fd0f104e16540a4"), "field" : "1,2,3,7,8,9,0,4,3" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("506001926fd0f104e16540a5"), "field" : "1" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("506001966fd0f104e16540a6"), "field" : "1,5" }
```

Then you can run the following map/reduce queries to achieve what you want.

```
map = function() {
    var array = this.field.split(',');
    emit(this.field, array.length);
}

reduce = function(key, values) {
    return values;
}

result = db.runCommand({
        "mapreduce" : "comma", 
        "map" : map,
        "reduce" : reduce,
        "out" : "comma_result"
});
```

The result is :

```
> db.comma_result.find();
{ "_id" : "1", "value" : 1 }
{ "_id" : "1,2,3", "value" : 3 }
{ "_id" : "1,2,3,4,5", "value" : 5 }
{ "_id" : "1,2,3,7,8,9,0,4,3", "value" : 9 }
{ "_id" : "1,5", "value" : 2 }
```

Comment: I need Mapreduce function to Join two collections.kindly help me.

Comment: You should be more specific in your question. Edit your question and add more details.This is the answer of the question you ask above.

Comment: Sorry,Am a beginner in mongoDB.I have two collections Book and author.[name and workswritten] are the common column respectively.using inner join i have to emit the some columns in Book and Author..like this sql query(select book.name,book.editions,book.characters,author.name from dbo.book book 
inner join dbo.author author on book.name=author.works_written)i need to do this same query in MongoDB.(Mapreduce).

Comment: I am using your code as following but i got an error listed below.plz guide me(all string value in character field)

map = function() {
    var array=new Array();

    array = this.characters.split(',');
    emit(this.characters,array.length);
}
reduce = function(key, values) {
    return values;
}
result = db.runCommand({
        "mapreduce" : "book", 
        "map" : map,
        "reduce" : reduce,
        "out" : "comma_result"
});

ERROR:

"errmsg" : "exception: reduce -> multiple not supported yet",
"code" : 10075,
"ok" : 0